# Search between the third and forth occurrence in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string that contains some text:

Example:

```
XPTOP XPTOP 4WS00632 BLACK VERNIS
```

I want to extract only

```
4WS00632
```

and ignore everything else.

I did try indexing the spaces, using charindex for searching all the spaces and then a substring to start at x, end at y.

But, no luck. Sometimes it returns "4WS0063" or "P 4WS00632".
This data is not coherent only "XPTOP XPTOP" is somewhat coherent.
For instance "4WS00632" this has 8 digits, but it might have 9 or 12.

So, I really need to catch everything in between the 3rd space and 4th space.

Comment: Can you post the SQL that you've tried so far? And the instance of data that doesn't cooperate?

Comment: SQL Server has a bunch of string functions that will help you to accomplish this.

Comment: FYI Microsoft SQL could be SQL Server or MS Access.

Comment: For instace

"XYZ XYZ JW2B0037VK3 S17 SENAPE BLACK)"

I would imagine that getting the length first to the second space and then to the third would 

`LEFT(reFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR) + 1)),
LEFT(reffar, charindex(' ', REFFAR, charindex(' ' , REFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR) + 1) + 1)),´

and then `SUBSTRING(REFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR) + 1), charindex(' ', REFFAR, charindex(' ' , REFFAR, charindex(' ', REFFAR) + 1) + 1))

1 Left: `XYZ XYZ´ - Right
2 Left: `XYZ XYZ JW2B0037VK3´

3 Substring: ` JW2B0037VK3 S17 SENAPE BLACK´
´

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yet another option is with a bit of JSON

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=784eb9b7067ee30abace470b34924fd1)**

```
Select A.SomeCol
      ,NewVal = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(SomeCol,' ','","')+'"]','$[2]')
 From YourTable  A
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                                 NewVal
XPTOP XPTOP 4WS00632 BLACK VERNIS       4WS00632
```

Comment: Hi John, let me join to the party :-) You passed me by, congrats! As always: Good answer, +1 from my side :-))

Comment: @Shnugo In good looks ... It will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this technique:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'XPTOP XPTOP 4WS00632 BLACK VERNIS';

DECLARE @text_xml XML = '<a>' + REPLACE(@text, ' ', '</a><a>')+ '</a>';

WITH DataSource (element_pos, element_text) AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
           ,T.c.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
    FROM @text_xml.nodes('a') T(c)
)
SELECT element_text
FROM DataSource
WHERE element_pos = 3;
```

The idea is to split the string by `space` and order the `strings` by their position. Then simply get the 3rd one.

Comment: This works, but I need to query over an existing table. And  I don't any technique to declare a variable with an existing table. I will study this and try to figure it out.

Comment: @gotqn, please connect with me on LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of using a combination of `charindex` and `stuff`.

It could be done in a single statement but I broke it into a couple of logical steps to make it clearer.

```
create table #test (col1 varchar(100))
insert into #test values ('XPTOP XPTOP 4WS00632 BLACK VERNIS')
    
with s1(s) as (select Stuff(col1,1,CharIndex(' ',col1),'') from #test),
s2(s) as (select Stuff(s,1, CharIndex(' ',s),'') from s1)

select Left(s, charIndex(' ',s) )
from s2;
```

Comment: This also works, but I need to query over an existing table and I have no clue. I will also study this possibility and adapt it to my existing table

Comment: @AntónioMiranda you can easily adapt to a table, just replace @s with your column name and in the first `CTE` select `from tablename`. I have edited above for you.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `string_split()` along with some `like` comparisons:

```
select t.*, s.value
from t cross apply
     (select s.value
      from string_split(t.str, ' ') s
      where t.str like concat('% % % ', s.value, ' %') and
            t.str not like concat('% % % % ', s.value, ' %')
     ) s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using charindex - and substring:

```
Declare @testTable Table (TestString varchar(100));
 Insert Into @testTable (TestString)
 Values ('XPTOP XPTOP 4WS00632 BLACK VERNIS')
      , ('XYZ XYZ JW2B0037VK3 S17 SENAPE BLACK');

 Select tt.TestString
      , part1 = ltrim(substring(v.TestString, 1, p01.pos - 2))
      , part2 = ltrim(substring(v.TestString, p01.pos, p02.pos - p01.pos - 1))
      , part3 = ltrim(substring(v.TestString, p02.pos, p03.pos - p02.pos - 1))
   From @testTable                                                      As tt
  Cross Apply (Values (concat(tt.TestString, replicate(' ', 3))))       As v(TestString)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(' ', v.TestString, 1) + 1))            As p01(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(' ', v.TestString, p01.pos) + 1))      As p02(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex(' ', v.TestString, p02.pos) + 1))      As p03(pos)
```